# Database Schema for One to Many or Many to Many using JSON Arrays

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

Should the schema for 1 to many or many to many relationship be better using JSON arrays or traditional relation tables for best performance using mysql (planetscale).

- Using arrays only 1 table is used:

[image]

- For Many to Many using 3 table

[image]

Similarly in case of 1 to many would arrays be much better?

I have seen that json arrays need to be stored as binary but is that better than having another table and indexing all of the values.

Follow up question:

I will also need to store likes, comments, collaborators. Can those also be stored using the similar approach of arrays/relation tables

Comment: You cannot create foreign key on JSON column which stores an array. Your relation is clear M:N, so variant 2 with adjacency table is the only option.

Comment: Can I store them without a foreign key in a unstructured way, each post storing its own array of tags without any reference.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is not better to use JSON for the references you describe, but it depends on the queries you need to run.

**JSON is worse for query flexibility.**

Like any form of denormalization, JSON improves one thing (flexibility of structure), at the expense of all other aspects of data storage and querying.

If you must optimize one specific query — fetching the whole array from the primary table — and you don't care about the efficiency of anything else, then perhaps denormalization is justified. But that's a pretty rare situation.

**JSON is worse for code complexity.**

Many people struggle with writing queries when their data is stored in JSON format. Just review some of the past questions in the [mysql-json](/questions/tagged/mysql-json) tag. Querying and updating data in JSON takes a lot more expertise and results in long queries that take longer to develop, are harder to read and debug, and end up costing your employer more, because a task that takes minutes to develop for  normalized SQL tables might take days when you use JSON.

If you don't believe me, I suggest you prototype the queries you will need to run in your application. How long does it take you to develop a query to, for example, join your many-to-many array to the related table? How about developing an UPDATE to add an element to the array, making sure you don't add a duplicate value that is already in the array?

**JSON is worse for performance.**

MySQL 8.0 supports [multi-valued keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued), so you can create an index on a JSON array, but there are limitations, and you can't always create an index on arbitrary JSON. Without an index, searching the JSON array might have to resort to a table-scan, which results in poor performance.

**JSON is worse for referential integrity.**

Currently the implementation doesn't support defining a foreign key constraint on the values in the multi-value key.

Without a foreign key constraint, you have no assurance that all the values in your array are really references to data that exists in the referenced table. What if you delete a row in that other table? Did you remember to update the JSON array to remove the value that you deleted? How do you know this is true for all the values in the array? How would you check them?

**JSON is worse for storage.**

Storing the same data in JSON consumes 2-3 times as much storage space. If you are paying for storage (e.g. in the cloud), this will increase your costs.

**The bottom line**

Basically, JSON is good only when you really need to store semi-structured data. The use case you described, a simple array that mimics a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship, has a very predictable structure, so it would be better in almost every way to store it as normal rows and columns.

For a many-to-many relationship, the standard solution is to create a third table. Why are you trying to avoid this? It is *more* efficient in every way than using JSON.